# Table cells not high enough for content in tabu table with multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, tabu

I need some help to get my table right. I already tried a lot but nothing helps.

I got the following table:

```
\begin{tabu}{X[2,l,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[2,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]}

    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Wholesale markets} \\\hline

    \multicolumn2{l|}{\textbf{Terminology}} & \textbf{Tot. Volume Traded} & \textbf{DR Access \& Participation} & \hspace{0pt}\textbf{Aggregated DR Accepted} & \hspace{0pt}\textbf{Aggregated generation} \\\hline

    \multicolumn2{l|}{EPEX Spot Day Ahead} & \SI{235}{\tera\watt\hour} (2016) & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} \\\hline

    \multicolumn2{l|}{EPEX Spot Intraday} & \SI{41}{\tera\watt\hour} (2016) & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} \\\hline

    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Balancing and ancillary services} \\\hline

    \rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn2{l|}{Terminology} & Tot. Capacity Contracted & DR Access \& Participation & \hspace{0pt}Aggregated DR Accepted & \hspace{0pt}Aggregated generation \\\hline

    Primary control reserve & +/-- & \SI{830}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\hline

    \multirow{2}{=}{Secondary control reserve} & SCR + & \SI{1976}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\cline{2-6}

    & SCR -- & \SI{1907}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\hline

    \multirow{2}{=}{Minute reserve} & MR + & \SI{1850}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\cline{2-6}

    & MR -- & \SI{1654}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Immediately interruptible loads (SOL) --- AbLaV} & \SI{750}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & DR only programme \\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Quickly interruptible loads (SNL) --- AbLaV} & \SI{750}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & DR only programme \\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\multirow{2}{=}{Re-dispatch (Winter reserve)}} & 2016/17: \SI{8300}{\mega\watt} & \multirow{2}{=}{\hfill\ding{55}\hfill} & \multirow{2}{=}{\hfill\ding{55}\hfill} & \multirow{2}{=}{\hfill\ding{55}\hfill} \\

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{} & 2017/18: \SI{7000}{\mega\watt} & & &\\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Capacity Reserve} & \SI{2000}{\mega\watt} for October 2018 --- September 2020 & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} \\

\end{tabu}
```

When I compile(required packages as far I can tell: siunitx,pifont,multirow,tabu) it I get the following result:

[image: Result]

The problem is that some cell contents are higher than their cells, which I marked with red in the image.

Comment: try to employ `makecell` package and write for example `\makecell{2016/17\\\SI{8300}{MW}\\20017/18\\ \SI{7000}{MW} ` for futher help please extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table, which we can copy and compile. on the first sight, table code is unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of `\tabulinesep` for that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx, pifont, multirow, tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep =4pt
\begin{tabu}{X[2,l,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[2,c,m] |X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]}

    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Wholesale markets} \\\hline

    \multicolumn2{l|}{\textbf{Terminology}} & \textbf{Tot. Volume Traded} & \textbf{DR Access \& Participation} & \hspace{0pt}\textbf{Aggregated DR Accepted} & \hspace{0pt}\textbf{Aggregated generation} \\\hline

    \multicolumn2{l|}{EPEX Spot Day Ahead} & \SI{235}{\tera\watt\hour} (2016) & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} \\\hline

    \multicolumn2{l|}{EPEX Spot Intraday} & \SI{41}{\tera\watt\hour} (2016) & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} \\\hline

    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Balancing and ancillary services} \\\hline

    \rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn2{l|}{Terminology} & Tot. Capacity Contracted & DR Access \& Participation & \hspace{0pt}Aggregated DR Accepted & \hspace{0pt}Aggregated generation \\\hline

    Primary control reserve & +/-- & \SI{830}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\hline

    \multirow{2}{=}{Secondary control reserve} & SCR + & \SI{1976}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\cline{2-6}

    & SCR -- & \SI{1907}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\hline

    \multirow{2}{=}{Minute reserve} & MR + & \SI{1850}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\cline{2-6}

    & MR -- & \SI{1654}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}\\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Immediately interruptible loads (SOL) --- AbLaV} & \SI{750}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & DR only programme \\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Quickly interruptible loads (SNL) --- AbLaV} & \SI{750}{\mega\watt} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & DR only programme \\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\multirow{2}{=}{Re-dispatch (Winter reserve)}} & 2016/17: \SI{8300}{\mega\watt} & \multirow{2}{=}{\hfill\ding{55}\hfill} & \multirow{2}{=}{\hfill\ding{55}\hfill} & \multirow{2}{=}{\hfill\ding{55}\hfill} \\

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{} & 2017/18: \SI{7000}{\mega\watt} & & &\\\hline

    \multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr 3\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Capacity Reserve} & \SI{2000}{\mega\watt} for October 2018 --- September 2020 & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} \\

\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]